# Heroku, namecheap and email forwarding

Tags: heroku, dns, namecheap

I have a free dyno on heroku for an app `myapp` and I've just bought a domain `myapp.co`. I would like to configure Namecheap so both of the following are true:

1. A user enters `myapp.co` in the URL -> my Heroku app is displayed under `myapp.co` URL
2. A user enters `www.myapp.co` in the RUL -> my Heroku app is displayed under `myapp.co` URL

**What I 've already done is added 2 domains in Heroku settings and they look like this:**

1. **Domain name:** `myapp.co` **DNS Target:** `autogenerated-heroku-slug-1.herokudns.com`
2. **Domain name:** `www.myapp.co` **DNS Target:** `autogenerated-heroku-slug-2.herokudns.com`

**I've already added 3 host records in the Advanced DNS section of Namecheap:**

1. **Type:** `CNAME Record` **Host:** `@` **Value:** `autogenerated-heroku-slug-1.herokudns.com.`
2. **Type:** `CNAME Record` **Host:** `www` **Value:** `autogenerated-heroku-slug-2.herokudns.com.`
3. **Type:** `URL Redirect Record` **Host:** `@` **Value:** `http://myapp.co/   Unmasked`

Trying to access `myapp.co` brings a page `This page isn't redirecting properly`.

How to properly configure both Heroku and Namecheap to make this work?

PS Not sure if this is an important part, but I would also like to user Namecheap email forwarding so emails sent to `contact@myapp.co` are redirected to my gmail account.

Answer (score 1):

I would instead do:

1. **Type**: CNAME Record **Host**: @ **Value**: yourappname.herokuapp.com
2. **Type**: CNAME Record **Host**: www **Value**: yourappname.herokuapp.com

Wait for a couple of minutes for the DNS records to be configured and try again.